# Expect: Check that a string is not a substring of another string

Tags: expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]

spawn su $user
expect "Password:"

send "$password\r";

expect {
        #"*" {puts "Login successfulklk"; exit 0}
        timeout {puts "Unable to su user"; exit -1}
        "su: incorrect password" {puts "Incorrect Password" ; exit -1}
        eof {puts "Closed \n";exit -1}
        "!su: incorrect password]*" {puts "Login successfull"; exit 0}
}
```

I want a clause in the expect which checks that string ("su: incorrect password") is not a substring of another string.

Comment: Usally the first line contains a path to the command line interpreter, and I dont know one named "expect"

Comment: Typically, you would put a *positive* pattern to search for, not a *lack* of some string. For example, you would know the user's promprt, and expect to see that.